# Animation not started when new properties are received

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a list of items(each of which is made from an image) and I would like to increase the size of each one in turn. Therefore, I am firing an action with the index of each item, in turn. Whenever the current item sees that the index fired in the action is also its own, it starts an animation that increases its size.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.index == this.props.ordinalNumber) {
        console.log("STARTING ANIMATION!!!");
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
            toValue: 1.5,
            duration: 1000
        }).start();
    }
}
```

In my `render()` method, I am adjusting the height and the width based upon `animatedValue`.

```
const animatedStyle = {width: 0.5 * this.props.dimensions.windowWidth * parseInt(JSON.stringify(this.animatedValue)),
        height: 0.5 * this.props.dimensions.windowHeight * parseInt(JSON.stringify(this.animatedValue))};
```

I am returning this from `render()`:

```
       <View>
         <Animated.Image
             source={{uri: this.props.imageUrl}}
             style={[this.getImageStyle(), animatedStyle]}>
         </Animated.Image>
       </View>
```

`this.animatedValue` is initialised in the constructor like this:

```
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1);
```

The problem is that the images' sizes are not increased(even though `"STARTING ANIMATION!!!"` is printed, which means that control reaches `componentWillReceiveProps`).

Any idea why the animation does not occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Animated values like simple primitives, because they are objects that wraps async changes over time.. Of course this trick: `parseInt(JSON.stringify(this.animatedValue))` works, but would not change all related calculations constantly.

From the official doc:

> Animated exports four animatable component types: View, Text, Image

So you have to pass Animated.Value directly to animatable components.

```js
<Animated.Image
    style={{
      width: this.animatedValueWidth
    }}
  />;
```

And move calculation of desired width and height based on props into `componentWillRecieveProps` where `Animated.timing` starts:

```js
Animated.timing(this.animatedValueWidth, {
  toValue: 1.5 * nextProps.dimensions.windowWidth
```

Also, you have to separate width and height into different animated values and than join both animations with `Animated.parallel`.
He re is fully working example based on your code bellow:

```js
  class AnimateImage extends React.Component {
    getImageStyle = () => ({});

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.animatedValueWidth = new Animated.Value(0);
      this.animatedValueHeight = new Animated.Value(0);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps({
      dimensions: { windowWidth, windowHeight } = {}
    }) {
      console.log("STARTING ANIMATION!!!");
      Animated.parallel([
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValueWidth, {
          toValue: 1.5 * windowWidth,
          duration: 1000
        }).start(),

        Animated.timing(this.animatedValueHeight, {
          toValue: 1.5 * windowHeight,
          duration: 1000
        }).start()
      ]);
    }

    render() {
      const animatedStyle = {
        width: this.animatedValueWidth,
        height: this.animatedValueHeight
      };
      return (
        <View>
          <Animated.Image
            source={{ uri: this.props.imageUrl }}
            style={[this.getImageStyle(), animatedStyle]}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <AnimateImage
          imageUrl={
            "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
          }
          dimensions={{
            windowWidth: 300,
            windowHeight: 300
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```

Note that you have an error of using `Animated.Image` , it should be auto closing tag:

```js
<Animated.Image
  source={{uri: this.props.imageUrl}}
  style={[this.getImageStyle(), animatedStyle]}>
/>
```